# Button blur does not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiblureffect

How can I make a button which get blurred? Behind the button is a image.

This is my code:

```
        let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.regular))
        blur.frame = cell.lvlBut.bounds
        blur.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        blur.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * cell.lvlBut.bounds.size.width
        blur.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.lvlBut.insertSubview(blur, at: 0)
```

The blur does not work perfectly, see image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just set the button `background color` and its `opacity` according to your requirement.

[image]